# Fill a column with multiple conditions from other columns

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to fill a column according to other conditions?

I made a false algorithm:

```
if (df.b == 3) & (df.c == 0) & (df.a == None):
    df['d'] == 0
else:
    df['b']
```

and I tried

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame([{'a': None, 'b': 3, 'c': 0},
           {'a': "string", 'b': 0, 'c': 3},
           {'a': "string", 'b': 3, 'c': 0}])

df['d'] = [0 if ((df.b == 3) & (df.c == 0) & (df.a == None)) else pass]
```

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I need

```
df = pandas.DataFrame([{'a': None, 'b': 3, 'c': 0, 'd': 0},
           {'a': "string", 'b': 0, 'c': 3, 'd': 0},
           {'a': "string", 'b': 3, 'c': 0, 'd': 3}])
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, [`Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html)

```
df['d'] = df['b'].mask(df['b'].eq(3) & df['c'].eq(0) & df['a'].isnull(), 0)

print (df)
        a  b  c  d
0    None  3  0  0
1  string  0  3  0
2  string  3  0  3
```

Comment: Alternative: `df.apply(lambda x:0 if x[0]==None and x[1]==3 and x[2]==0 else x[1],axis=1)` this is not better than yours. Nice answer. already +1ed

Comment: Thanks : ), I think we shouldn't use apply here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code @ Ch3steR

Comment: You are welcome:)  
I used to always use apply, it is a very common mistake, now I always think twice..  @Ch3steR

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [`isnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.isnull.html)to get where a is `None`.

```
import numpy as np

df['d'] = np.where((df.b == 3) & (df.c == 0) & (df.a.isnull()), 0, df['b'])
print (df)
        a  b  c  d
0    None  3  0  0
1  string  0  3  0
2  string  3  0  3
```

Answer (score 1):

df['d'] = df['b'].mask(df['b'].eq(3) & df['c'].eq(0) & df['a'].isnull(), 0)

print (df)
        a  b  c  d
0    None  3  0  0
1  string  0  3  0
2  string  3  0  3